# Convey the idea of partial similarity in a list of things in a sentence/

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I have the following sentence:

> Surveyed meta-heuristics techniques like Tabu Search, Simulated annealing and Constraint Satisfaction Problem(CSP).

The problem is **CSP** is not a **meta-heuristic**. How can I convey the idea that only two things after **like** are similar and not the thing after **and**.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *Surveyed meta-heuristics techniques like Tabu Search and Simulated Annealing, **and other techniques such as** Constraint Satisfaction Problem(CSP).*

Comment: Can this not be done with the help of any punctuation?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid punctuation? Punctuation helps readers understand the structure of complicated utterances.

Comment: @Aman Deep Gautam: Punctuation doesn't even *exist* in "real" (spoken) English. Since there's obviously no way to convey your intended sense using the exact words as presented, simply by intonation, the answer to that one must be *"No!"*

Comment: Surveyed meta-heuristics-like techniques such as Tabu Search, Simulated annealing and Constraint Satisfaction Problem(CSP).

Comment: Surveyed meta-heuristics techniques like Tabu Search and Simulated annealing, and also surveyed Constraint Satisfaction Problem(CSP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to reorder the sentence so that *CSP* is not after *like*:

> Surveyed Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP) and meta-heuristics techniques such as Tabu Search and Simulated Annealing.

Another way is to use a different conjunction:

> Surveyed meta-heuristics techniques like Tabu Search and Simulated annealing, as well as Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP).